# Angular 2 and golden layout height not issue - not accepting percentage height

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, height, golden-layout

I am facing a tough issue with angular 2 and golden layout component not accepting height as percentage. (but styling the width to 100% works). 
Any help is much appreciated.

Plunker as in here : http://plnkr.co/edit/tUQOev?p=preview

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [TestService],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Value: {{testService.testValue}}</h2>
      <div><button (click)="testService.add()">Change Value</button></div>
      <div style class="layout" gl></div>
    </div>
  `, 
  styles: [
    `
    .layout{ width:100%; height:100%}
    `
  ]
  directives: [GlDirective]
})
```

1. When I give the **layout: Width : 100%; height : 400px** - it works fine as below

[image]

2. But when I try to give height : 100% layout simply does not recognize height and does not render correctly.

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your Plunker isn't working for me, but this looks a lot like standard CSS 100% height trickery.

Instead of using `height:100%` try using `height:100vh`

When you use `height:100%` you're saying the element should have the same height as its **parent**, but parent elements by default start off with 0 height and grow to fit their contents. So you end up with parent basing its height off the child and the child basing its height off the parent. Confusing, right? So it only works out if one of them uses a fixed height like when you used `height:400px` or something like `height:100vh` which means "as tall as the screen".

You can also check out [This Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474361/setting-full-height-of-angular-components) with more answers regarding the same issue.