# Setting full height of Angular Components

Tags: css, angular

I cannot get my list to be full height. My code is more complicated with nested components. But I can still get this to replicate using this code. Here is a plunk. http://plnkr.co/edit/R0QgLz8cjyRHYOLf4uJW

styles.css

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
```

app.component.css

```
.container {
height: 100%;
background: black;
color: white;
```

list.component.css

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.list {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  border-right: groove white 1px;
  border-top: groove white 1px;
}
.item {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}
```

list.component.html

```
<div class="contents">
  <button (click)="updateDocuments()">Update Document</button>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="list">
      <div *ngFor="let document of documents; let i = index;">
        {{i + 1}}. {{document}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      this is an item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I got this to work by switching to height 100vh and also adding a overflow-y: scroll css attribute to the list and item classes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/R0QgLz8cjyRHYOLf4uJW

styles.css

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
```

app.component.css

```
.container {
height: 100vh;
background: black;
color: white;
```

list.component.css

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.list {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  border-right: groove white 1px;
  border-top: groove white 1px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.item {
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

list.component.html

```
<div class="contents">
  <button (click)="updateDocuments()">Update Document</button>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="list">
      <div *ngFor="let document of documents; let i = index;">
        {{i + 1}}. {{document}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      this is an item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

try to write this css

```
.container{
    min-height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: Try explaining what `100vh` means, this question might solve the problem, but doesn't explain what is happening and why.

Comment: I understand what 100vh means. But if I add 100vh this will only take it to the viewable height. Not if anything gets pushed past that.

Answer (score 4):

Use `position: fixed` if that's acceptable:

```
.container {
  position:fixed;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I wish this worked. If my list is longer than viewable height, I can't scroll.

Comment: You just overflow it?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. While I can see this working, the problem was when the data was dynamic it would remove the border I had set on elements. Adding a scroll bar on both elements took care of my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "just overflow it"?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, and found that the best solution was:

```
html, body {
  min-height:100vh;
  height: auto;
}
```

and for the container:

```
.container{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi everyone who faced this problem
Just go to global css file, it has the comment

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
```

written in it. Add

```
*{margin:0; padding:0}
```

that's it

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in the Internet:

> The reason for this issue is concealed in the way a browser interprets
> the host element, which doesn’t know it’s an HTML element at all and
> so the browser sets the default display value (inline) for the host
> element.

So probably it's enough just to redefine again "display" property for "host" tag (add in your component code) :

```
host: {
  display: flex; /*or whatever is fit your needs*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try in your style.css

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: this works to get the height to the viewable height. But if I have a dynamic list that is fluid and not always the same height this does not work. Especially if I am adding a border to the list.